# how to get date difference between rows for each 100th instance in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table where my product subscription data is recorded like date, amount, product, plan. I want to show the difference in days for every 100 subscriptions.

### Subscription Range | Days

1-100 | 10 days

101-200 | 7 days

201-300 | 8 days

Please help me with the query to achieve this.

Comment: please provide few sample data where all combination will fulfill

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with your issues, but there certain expectations you are expected to meet. Please take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/) and to review [ask[. In particular what have you tried, what are the table definitions (ddl), and post sample date with expected results, all as text - **no images**.  Without that there is not much the community can offer.